# Where to get info on special character sequences

Tags: linux, unix, curses

Could anybody be so kind to give me a link where I can get enough of information about special character sequences like "\033[0m"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), there are understood by the terminal emulator like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` (and in the 1970s by real terminals like [VT100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100); see [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)). See [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap), [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html), [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html), [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) etc...

<sup>In the previous century, escape codes have been terminal specific!</sup>

You probably want to use some terminal I/O library like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) (then avoid expliciting escape codes, `ncurses` will do that), or, for input only [GNU readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline).